# Python train convolutional neural network on csv numpy error input shape

Tags: python, keras, conv-neural-network

I would like to train a convolutional neural network autoencoder on a csv file. The csv file contains pixel neighborhood position of an original image of 1024x1024.
When I try to train it, I have the following error that I don't manage to resolve.
`ValueError: Input 0 of layer max_pooling2d is incompatible with the layer: expected ndim=4, found ndim=5. Full shape received: (None, 1, 1024, 1024, 16)`. Any idea, what I am doing wrong in my coding?

Let's me explain my code:

My csv file has this structure:

```
0 0 1.875223e+01
1 0 1.875223e+01
2 0 2.637685e+01
3 0 2.637685e+01
4 0 2.637685e+01
```

I managed to load my dataset, extract the x, y, and value columns as NumPy arrays and extract the relevant columns as NumPy arrays

```
x = data[0].values
y = data[1].values
values = data[2].values
```

Then, I create an empty image with the correct dimensions and fill in the image with the pixel values

```
image = np.empty((1024, 1024))


for i, (xi, yi, value) in enumerate(zip(x, y, values)):
    image[xi.astype(int), yi.astype(int)] = value
```

To use this array as input to my convolutional autoencoder I reshaped it to a 4D array with dimensions

```
# Reshape the image array to a 4D tensor
image = image.reshape((1, image.shape[0], image.shape[1], 1))
```

Finally, I declare the convolutional autoencoder structure, at this stage I have the error `incompatible with the layer: expected ndim=4, found ndim=5. Full shape received: (None, 1, 1024, 1024, 16)'

```
import keras
from keras.layers import Input, Conv2D, MaxPooling2D, UpSampling2D
from keras.models import Model

# Define the input layer
input_layer = Input(shape=(1,image.shape[1], image.shape[2], 1))

# Define the encoder layers
x = Conv2D(16, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(input_layer)
x = MaxPooling2D((2, 2), padding='same')(x)
x = Conv2D(8, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(x)
x = MaxPooling2D((2, 2), padding='same')(x)
x = Conv2D(8, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(x)
encoded = MaxPooling2D((2, 2), padding='same')(x)

# Define the decoder layers
x = Conv2D(8, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(encoded)
x = UpSampling2D((2, 2))(x)
x = Conv2D(8, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(x)
x = UpSampling2D((2, 2))(x)
x = Conv2D(16, (3, 3), activation='relu')(x)
x = UpSampling2D((2, 2))(x)
decoded = Conv2D(1, (3, 3), activation='sigmoid', padding='same')(x)

# Define the autoencoder model
autoencoder = Model(input_layer, decoded)

# Compile the model
autoencoder.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='binary_crossentropy')

# Reshape the image array to a 4D tensor
image = image.reshape((1, image.shape[0], image.shape[1], 1))

# Train the model
autoencoder.fit(image, image, epochs=50, batch_size=1, shuffle=True)
```

Comment: I also tried also `Reshape the image array to a 4D tensor
image = image.reshape((1, image.shape[0], image.shape[1], 1))` but I have this error: `ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 1048576 into shape (1,1,1024,1)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should drop the first dimension in the input layer:

```python
input_layer = Input(shape=(image.shape[1], image.shape[2], 1))
```

Training pool shape and input layer shape should be different. Input layer shape describes the shape of a single datapoint, while training pool shape describes whole dataset. Hence it has one more dimension with size equal to the number of data points in your dataset.

You should also drop second `image.reshape` since at that time `image.shape == (1, 1024, 1024, 1)` and doing `image = image.reshape((1, image.shape[0], image.shape[1], 1))` tries to reshape that into `(1, 1, 1024, 1)` which is impossible.

And lastly you forgot to add `padding='same'` to one of the `Conv2D` layers. Add that to match output layer shape with your training label shape.

Comment: thanks for passing time to answer me. The second image reshape, you mean the one after the `compile model`? I added `x = Reshape((x.shape[1], x.shape[2], x.shape[3]))(x)` just after the first Conv2D, but it seems not having an influence.

Comment: Yes I meant that one. Just remove that line.

Comment: You were right @Alex, I also forgot `padding='same'` to one of my `Conv2D` layers. Your advices helped me alot. I just I have another issue, I have the loss the negative during the training but I think it can be due to something wrong with my model or the data I am using